# Objective C: Memory Management, releasing an object with multiple references

Tags: objective-c

I would like to release a Car object present in the dealer. I would like to know what is the right way of doing it. NSMutableArray Inventory stores the cars for a particular dealer. So, now I would like to present the user with a delete functionality, so, user could select the car using the Vin Number and delete it. But if I try to find the car and release the reference that doesn't works. Would I need to remove the object from the Array and then, release the reference? I am fairly new to objective c and in the initial learning phase. Thank you.

```
#import "Dealer.h"
#import "Address.h"
#import "PhoneNumber.h"

@implementation Dealer

static NSInteger dealerIdAllocater = 0;

-(id) init{
    self = [super init];
    self.dealerId = ++dealerIdAllocater;
    self.addressList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.inventory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return self;
}

@synthesize dealerId, name, addressList, inventory;

-(void)addCarInInventory:(Car*)car{
    [self.inventory addObject: car];
}

-(void)displayAddresses{
    for(Address *address in self.addressList){
        NSLog(@"Street Address: %@", address.streetAddress);
        NSLog(@"City: %@", address.city);
        NSLog(@"State: %@", address.state);
        NSLog(@"Country: %@", address.country);
        for(int i=0; i<[address.phoneNumber count]; i++){
            PhoneNumber *phoneNumber = [address.phoneNumber objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"Phone Number %i, %@", i, phoneNumber.phoneNumber);
        }
        NSLog(@"--------------");
    }
}

-(void)displayInventory{
    for(Car *car in self.inventory){
        [car displayInformation];
    }
    NSLog(@"--------------");
}

-(Car *)findCarById:(NSString *)vinNumber{
    for(Car *car in self.inventory){
        if ([vinNumber isEqualToString:car.vinNumber]) {
            return car;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would I need to remove the object from the Array and then, release the reference?

Yes, containers such as `NSMutableArray`s increment the retain count of objects by 1 when added to them. This is to make sure the container will always hold a valid reference to an object. When you remove an object from the container, the retain count will be decremented by 1.